# Change cmp.set value based on field value

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to tweak a custom lightning component a third-party developer created in our org.

Current code below:

```
 * This downloads the current student budget from the backend and kicks off
 * the processing of all the data.
 */
getStudentBudget: function(cmp, ev, helper) {
    var action = cmp.get('c.getStudentBudget');

    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        var ret = a.getReturnValue();

        if (ret) {                
            cmp.set('v.budgetForm', ret);
            cmp.set('v.showLaunchButton', true);
            helper.updateTerms(cmp);
            helper.isStepValid(cmp, ev, helper);
            helper.processTransportationTypes(cmp, helper);
            helper.populateFinancialAid(cmp, helper);
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Currently, variable "v.showLuanchButton" is being set to TRUE based on whether a certain field on the "StudentBudget" record is checked off or not. I want to change which field is being considered for that change.

What I'm imagining is something like this:

```
 * This downloads the current student budget from the backend and kicks off
 * the processing of all the data.
 */
getStudentBudget: function(cmp, ev, helper) {
    var action = cmp.get('c.getStudentBudget');

    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        var ret = a.getReturnValue();

        if (ret) {                
            cmp.set('v.budgetForm', ret);

*************************NEW PART HERE***************************
              if (Boolean_field_I_want__c) {
                  cmp.set('v.showLaunchButton', true);
              }
*****************************************************************

            helper.updateTerms(cmp);
            helper.isStepValid(cmp, ev, helper);
            helper.processTransportationTypes(cmp, helper);
            helper.populateFinancialAid(cmp, helper);
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

What I don't know how to do is how to access the value of "Boolean_field_I_want__c".

Answer (score 1):

If the response is a single record, you should be able to use dot notation, like this:

```
if(ret.Boolean_field_I_want__c){
    cmp.set('v.showLaunchButton', true);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shane - that managed to remove the launch button, but it also removed a listview displayed on the same page. Any idea why this might be the case? The listview is part of a "Record List" component

Comment: @Jwok -- I'm not sure.  Post the relevant parts of the code and I'll take a look.